# How to reload Oracle APEX 5.0 Tree dynamically

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I need to reload full tree with new parameters when an event is triggered (say a button is clicked) an item value is set and new item value need to be used in Tree SQL.

Tree nodes are not refreshing When I try to refresh tree region using "Refresh" action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tree widget supports a whole host of advanced operations. The problem is the apex team has never exposed these options to developers. Instead they chose to mimic the technique they used for the old tree. While that tree also supported far more than what they ever exposed...
The short of it is that with both versions the data delivered to the tree is a json-payload in the render of the page. The tree consumes this and renders the nodes. Because of the "static" nature of its data it can not be refreshed.

Long story short: sorry, the tree as generated by apex does not support refreshing. You'll need to reload the page.