# Oracle APEX | How to refresh Tree after Dialog Page Closed

Tags: tree, oracle-apex-5

I want to Refresh tree region in the caller page (or submit page) after I close called dialog page.

Comment: There is no code related to this operation.

Comment: I open dialog page (page01) from the current opened page (page02)
After I do my work in dialog page (page01) and close it, I want (page02) to be submited.
how can I do that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Again, please post code. Can you also be more specific than "how can I do that?" What have you tried so far and what's going wrong with it?

Comment: I want (page02) to be submitted automatically by its self after I close dialog page (page01).

Comment: Right, but it's really hard to help you based only on the details you've provided, you really haven't given us enough context information to know what to help you with.

Answer (score 2):

Tree regions don't support native APEX refresh event. You can read some explanation in this question [How to reload Oracle APEX 5.0 Tree dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053517/how-to-reload-oracle-apex-5-0-tree-dynamically)

## But!

You can do it in a nasty way and by nasty I mean reload page through AJAX call to your current page with Tree region.

So, I assume you have 2 pages

- main page with tree region (page_id 10)
- modal page (page_id 11)

On main page you have

- tree region with static id `test`
- button `OPENPOPUP` opening the popup
- dynamic action bound to event `Dialog Closed` (selection type `button`, button `OPENPOPUP`)

  - true action `Execute JavaScript Code` - code that should refresh tree region

On popup page you have

- button `CLOSEPOPUP` with defined dynamic action that fires true action `Close Dialog`

This is the basics to bind main page and modal page. The thing you need is `Execute JavaScript Code` that will load newest version of the tree region each time the popup is closed with button `CLOSEPOPUP`.

I was courious is it possible to bypass lack of the refresh support. So I wrote my own `Execute JavaScript Code` to load only tree region from main page.

```
var 
  treeRegionStaticId = '#test',
  currentTree = $(treeRegionStaticId);
  parent = currentTree.parent();

$.ajax({
  url: apex.server.url ({}, $v('pFlowStepId')),
  dataType: 'html',
  method : 'GET',
  success: function( data ){
    var
      temp = $('<html />'),
      newTree,
      id;

    temp.html( data );
    //find region with id 'test'
    newTree = temp.find( treeRegionStaticId );
    //get id that is needed to call APEX tree constructor
    id = newTree.find('[aria-label="Tree"]').attr('id');
    //remove old tree region
    currentTree.remove();
    //append new tree region
    newTree.appendTo( parent );
    //call apex tree constructor
    eval( 'apex.widget.tree.init( \''+id+'\', {}, gT'+(id.substr(1, id.length))+'Data,"S","",true,false,false,"a-Icon")' )
  }
})
```

I have tested it on my local APEX 5 and each time I use `CLOSEPOPUP` button in modal page, the tree region is being refreshed after modal page close.

Code from above should be used as `Execute JavaScript code` in dynamic action bound to event `Dialog Closed` on main page.

Btw. the burden to the database is same as using `apex.submit` to reload page.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great effort, It remove the tree data but never build the tree again.

Comment: If you reproduce use case on apex.oracle.com I can look closer. All I need is workspace name and login credentials.

Comment: apex user name: sadammashaal@hotmail.com Pass: meshaal.
Project Name: sales
Page: Units Hierarchy
Dialog Page: Add/Edit Units.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Workspace: meshaal

Comment: In your example main page and modal page is not bound properly through dynamic action. No DA is executed after closing the modal. Instead of fixing your example I have imported my test application that I used to develop my answer - `APP_ID 42153`. Go to https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42153:10. 
Start from `page 10`, expand some tree leafs, click `POPUP` button, click `CLOSE` button. After closing the modal tree region is being refreshed. You can inspect it with console > network and see result of AJAX.
My example is working. Inspect my test pages and try to implement it.

Comment: The problem is when change happen to tree data (add , update , delete) the tree is removed but fail to be rebuilt.
But the DA that refresh the Interactive report after closing dialog page works without problems.
Any way Thank you so much for your great effort @bostrowski

Comment: I will investigate it :-) I want it to work and I'll inform you about results here, in comments. If my current answer was useful for you please vote for my answer :-) It's giving me a kick to do more and better :-)